# How to set the file encoding when getting file from Paramiko

Tags: python, encoding, sftp, paramiko

I'm working with the latest **Python 3**.
I'm trying to set the **file encoding** when getting a file with **Paramiko**.

Below a snippet of my code:

```
using paramiko
using csv

...

self._sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self._transport)

with self._sftp.file(filename) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    for line in reader:
        data.customer_name = line["customer_name"]
```

The file I'm trying to parse is a **text file** encoded in **ISO-8859-1** (Latin-1).

The file contains accent character like "èé".

When I launch my script I got the exception below:

```
def decode(self, input, final=False):
    # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    data = self.buffer + input
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
E       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 691: invalid continuation byte
```

The exception is raised on this line:

```
for line in reader:
```

I have try to search a solution to force the encoding when getting the file from Paramiko but I can't see any encoding parameter.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Imo, Paramiko won't convert the encoding for you. You have to do it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply !

I didn't manage to solve the problem so I change the way of getting the file. I download the file instead opening a stream and then I use pandas to read the csv.
Pandas got a parameter to set the encoding of the file.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. Or accept that the question is duplicate.